# Looking for a C++ GUI library in which you can design fancy GUIs (like for games),

Tags: c++, user-interface

Looking for a C++ GUI library in which you can design fancy GUIs (like for games), 
something in which you can make something beautiful (rounded buttons with rollover effects, embed beautiful background graphics, cool and colorful scrollbars and progress bars, etc.)

It needs to be open source & allowed to be used in proprietary software. Should be also cross-platform, and shouldn´t need to be linked to thousands of libraries or days to get the compiler configured to run even for small samples.

**I hope I´m not asking too much**

I tried CEGUI and I wasn´t convinced — it was tricky and I compiled the samples but they didn´t run on some computers.

QuickGUI seems to need OGRE (tell me if I´m wrong), which I don´t want to learn now.

Navi needs GeckoRuntime, which ist too big for my project!

wxWidgets doesn´t seem to be focused on design but on functionality (tell me if I´m wrong)

Comment: wxWidgets seems designed just fine to me. Oh, and as a user, I'd much rather use an application using the native buttons and controls. I absolutely hate when people reinvent the wheel (because, inevitably, they do it badly).

Comment: From wxWiki: "Concentrating on native looks also mean wx may not be best suited for applications that want a customized look instead of the system's theme."

Comment: Billy, that's called "reinventing the square wheel" :)

Comment: For games, it's custom to style controls themselves. Then again, gamers wouldn't say "as a user, I'd ...", but "as a gamer, I'd" - I don't think Billy ONeal was speaking as a gamer.

Answer (score 4):

Try [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), although it's more of a framework than a library. Both are widely used GUI toolkits. Hope that helps.

Comment: See FreeCiv (http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) for an example of a skinned GTK+ application.

Answer (score 3):

I believe libRocket is designed with game user interfaces in mind.

http://www.librocket.com/

Its based on HTML/CSS which, in my opinion, is an excellent way to define a user interface.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Qt. You can probably do much of what you are asking for using Qt. More specifically take a look at these features in Qt

- CSS Customizations of Qt Widgets
- QtOpenGL for 3D graphics ( if you need 3D graphics and need to embed Qt Widgets into a 3D environment).
- QGraphicsView for combining multiple widgets in different ways

When you download Qt, it comes with a set of demos. You can take a look at these demos and other examples and re-use the concepts of the parts you like.

I have worked with Qt quite a bit and I can confidently say that you can achieve just about anything you can imagine.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, can you tell me more about the license, please.. It needs to be open source & allowed to be used in proprietary software

Comment: Qt has a LGPL'ed release. So it is Open Source and you can use it for closed source applications as long as a you don't link statically to the Qt Library. However any changes you make to Qt itself has to be open-sourced.

Answer (score 0):

GuiChan? http://guichan.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Features

I haven't personally used it yet, but will intend to use it on a game I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Scaleform is a commerical solution.

http://www.scaleform.com/products/clik

Many people tell me good things about it.